# Can Android Studio be used to run standard Java projects?

Tags: android-studio, ide

For those times when you want to isolate the Java and give it a quick test..

Can you run non-Android Java projects in Android studio as in Eclipse?

Comment: Android studio is based upon intelliJ. So sure, it surely able to run "standard" java code. But why do you need it ?

Comment: @vmironov I agree with you.

Comment: @vmironov That's essentially what they're doing. The Android features are an IntelliJ plugin, they just package it together for Android Studio. I haven't used Android Studio in particular, but I've been using IntelliJ for a while, and you should have no issue running standard Java projects within it.

Comment: @kcoppock, yep, but this plugin cann't be added to a "usual" IntelliJ IDEA (I have a purchased Ultimate version and I don't really  want to switch back to Community edition). The Good news is that JetBrains has announced that it will be possible to have Android Studio's features in Intellij IDEA 13

Comment: So vmirinov are you saying that you can't run standard Android independent Java in Android Studio currently but that in the future, Android Studio will be made "pluggin-able" to IDEA 13 therefore giving you all the Android capability and Java capability in the same place?

Comment: Is there a simple way to get this to work with Gradle yet? I keep crashing because it cannot see my gradle libraries at runtime.

Comment: I would need to do this, for example, because I have helper apps such as sprite editors, animation editors, etc, which do not run on Android, but which are bespoke apps part of the development process.

Comment: My reason to do it is to work on some Kotlin tutorials that target the IntelliJ platform.  Everything is new for me at this point, Android, Android Studio, Kotlin, etc., so reducing number of IDEs just helps.

Comment: When I try to run a simple class, I get the error "SourceSet with name 'main' not found"

Answer (score 387, accepted):

**Tested on Android Studio 0.8.6 - 3.5**

Using this method you can have Java modules and Android modules in the same project and also have the ability to compile and run Java modules as stand alone Java projects.

1. Open your Android project in Android Studio. If you do not have one, create one.
2. Click **File > New Module**. Select **Java Library** and click **Next**.
3. Fill in the package name, etc and click **Finish**. You should now see a Java module inside your Android project.
4. Add your code to the Java module you've just created.
5. Click on the drop down to the left of the run button. Click **Edit Configurations...**
6. In the new window, click on the plus sign at the top left of the window and select **Application**
7. A new application configuration should appear, enter in the details such as your main class and classpath of your module.
8. Click **OK**.

Now if you click run, this should compile and run your Java module.

If you get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class...`, just enter your main class (as you've done in step 7) again even if the field is already filled in. Click **Apply** and then click **Ok**.

My usage case:
My Android app relies on some precomputed files to function. These precomputed files are generated by some Java code. Since these two things go hand in hand, it makes the most sense to have both of these modules in the same project.

**NEW - How to enable Kotlin in your standalone project**

If you want to enable Kotlin inside your standalone project, do the following.

1. Continuing from the last step above, add the following code to your project level `build.gradle` (lines to add are denoted by **>>>**):

   ```
   buildscript {
       >>> ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
           >>> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }
   ...
   ```
2. Add the following code to your module level `build.gradle` (lines to add are denoted by **>>>**):

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java-library'
   >>> apply plugin: 'kotlin'

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       >>> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
       >>> runtimeClasspath files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
   }
   ...
   ```
3. Bonus step: Convert your main function to Kotlin! Simply change your main class to:

   ```
   object Main {
       ...
       @JvmStatic
       fun main(args: Array<String>) {
           // do something
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I can confirm this works in Android Studio 0.8.14. I used a basic Hello World project, and added a Custom class containing a main method. I deleted the MainActivity.java file. At step 2, I needed to disclose the More Modules pane (bottom left of the Create New Module window) and scroll down to find the Java Library item. At step 6, I named my application, selected Custom as my main class, and app for the classpath of the module. NOTE: If you delete the app module, as per @simonp's solution, your application will run, but with errors.

Comment: There should be another step after step 2 : add code to the class, or at least make it a Hello-World code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: But how can I export a desktop project to a .jar file? I can't find that option anywhere :/

Comment: Is there a way of importing an existing java library project from say eclipse in AS (except of course of copy pasting the code in step 4 ?)

Comment: Thanks; your use case is identical to my own: I have a Java utility program that generates some files that are included as part of my app, which the app then uses.  So it makes sense to have these things in the same IDE.

Comment: Works in 2.2.2! :)

Comment: Did you integrate running the Java code into the build process for the Android app? If so, how did you do that?

Comment: @idunnololz Nice explanation and it works with Android Studio 3.0. Will the java module class files get added into APK when we generate it?

Comment: @Shail no it will not. As long as you did not modify the gradle build file, gradle will only build/package the Android project when you generate an APK.

Comment: Yes it does, I was able to make it run on 3.0.1 after several hacks, tweaks and gradle syncs. I had to add a `jar { }` configuration otherwise on runtime it won't find any dependencies (`Class not found` errors and the such)

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Foo

Comment: @Enam: try re-running it after that (works most of the time) and use `implementation` instead of `compile` in the module dependencies. And the only issue I have right now is reading app's resources.

Comment: If I remove the app module from the project structure I am forced to manually sync the project with gradle files to show the Java library folder at every project startup.
Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: worked great ! I used Android Studio 3.1.4. Thanks for sharing !

Comment: Worked on 3.5! Thanks!

Comment: I get this warning, after the code has been executed. It's a little annoying.    
 
"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings."

Comment: But what if my Java module uses Maven as the dependency management system not gradle?

Answer (score 28):

EDIT: many moon after this question was asked, yes, now apparently you can.

No, but it's based on Intellij IDEA.

The community version of that is free for download but it doesn't support most things requiring an external database or application server. The line for Java is pretty much that JavaSE code can happily use Community.

If you want that (or are using JavaEE) then you either need the Ultimate version, which isn't free, or the EAP of the next version which is usually good for a month until they release another.

Basically it works like this

Android Studio is just Android the Android Stuff from IDEA 13 Community...

...which will be free, and is anything from IDEA 13 Ultimate...

...that doesn't require a database or app server.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

IDEA 12 Community doesn't have the ability to import the gradilized project and it won't, so while you can do Android development in it now (I do), don't expect it to have the same features as Android Studio. There's a lot of good new Android stuff in it, that's going into 13.

Comment: Happy to help! I personally love IDEA and loathe Eclipse. This is the first time I've gone to playing with the EAP because I'm clearly going to need compatibility with everyone migrating to Android Studio.

Comment: As of AS 0.5.8, this is no longer correct. You can definitely run standard Java SE code in AS. At least I have success importing a Swing project, developing, and running it. Unfortunately, you cannot create a "regular" Java project as of this writing, at least not that I know of.

Comment: As of 0.6.1 you can.  See my answer below.

Comment: Please delete/edit this answer since it is no longer correct. Android Studio can now build Java modules and run them in the local JRE.

Comment: So it's better to use Android-Studio for android stuff, and IntelliJ for Java and the rest? What about SWT support on IntelliJ? Do you know of a nice UI designer for it? I need it mostly for preview of the UI .

Comment: Not deleting an answer as it has historical relevance but I updated it. Are SO users really expected to caretake their old SO questions and answers or is the date warning enough? I always thought it was because of stuff like this happening to my answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526074/android-activity-with-no-gui/6476811#6476811

Answer (score 25):

Easy way to run a java program in Android Studio would be,

1. Create a java Class says `"Test.java"` in Android Studio.
2. Write your code eg, a `Hello World` program to test.
3. Right-click on the Java class and:

- select the option `Run 'Test.main()'`

or

- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (on windows) or <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (on Mac)

There you have your Java code running below.

Comment: This worked - thanks! In my case I was having issues with the gradle build crashing, when first trying to run this.  So I did a `Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and then the issue was resolved

Comment: @Shruti It takes a while to compile the first time after switching from running the app to running the test.java. Do you know if the executable it's creating is added to the APK size at all?

Comment: For Kotlin: Click on the arrow next to `main()`, do NOT right-click the file or method name

Comment: On Mac, Run 'Test.main()' is now ⌃⇧R

Comment: It does not work for me. I get this: `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:MyClass.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.`

Comment: I also got the 'main' not found error, but then I chose "Run with Coverage" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 17):

With Android Studio 0.6.1+ (and possibly earlier) you can easily develop standard Java (non-Android) apps.

**This method has been tested on 0.8.2:**

Start by creating a vanilla Android Phone app, using File > New Project.  Then add a Java Library module to hold your Java Application code.  (Choose 'Java Library' even if you're building an application).  You'll find you can build and run Java apps with `main()` methods, Swing apps etc.

You'll want to delete the auto-generated Android "app" module, which you're not using.  Go to File -> Project Structure, and delete it (select the "app" module in the box on the left, and click the 'minus' icon above the box).   Now when you reopen File -> Project Structure -> Project, you'll see options for selecting the project SDK and language level, plus a bunch of other options that were previously hidden.  You can go ahead and delete the "app" module from the disk.

**In 0.6.1 you could avoid creating the android module in the first place:**

Go to File > New Project.   Fill in your application name.  On the "form factors" selection page, where you state your minimum Android SDK, **deselect** the Mobile checkbox, and proceed with creating your project.

Once the project is created, go to File -> Project Structure -> Project, and set your JDK as the "Project SDK".  Add a Java Library module to hold your application code as above.

Comment: Where can I find the build then? If I click Build->Make Project or Build->Compile 'PureJava.java' android studio says "Compilation completed successfully". But I can't find any build files. I deleted the app module as well as the app folder.

Comment: Have you been able to debug those projects?

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM yes it is possible. It has happened to me that when debugging, the IDE stalls at some point in the "updating indices" phase, I don't know what's causing it, I've tried cleaning caches and restarting.

Answer (score 16):

Here's exactly what the setup looks like.

[image]

**Edit Configurations > '+' > Application:**
[image]

Comment: HI Adam, can I know if it still works? And why would we need gradle for this application? Could the project be further cleaned up so just the bare minimum files are present?

Comment: Hi @Harsha, I implemented this as an experiment in 2016. I have not implemented this recently as I use standalone IntelliJ for backend Kotlin/Java applications. Feel free to update the comments/post with your updated findings.

Comment: I have done it in the same way. It is still working. I would like to start it from the command line but I can not find how to instruct Gradle to use the application configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I found a somewhat hacky, annoying and not-completely-sure-it-always-works solution to this. I wanted to share in case someone else finds it useful.

In Android Studio, you can right-click a class with a main method and select "Run .main()". This will create a new Run configuration for YourClass, although it won't quite work: it will be missing some classpath entries.

In order to fix the missing classpath entries, go into the Project Structure and manually add the output folder location for your module and any other module dependencies that you need, like so:

- File -> Project Structure ...
- Select "Modules" in the Project Settings panel on the left-column panel
- Select your module on the list of modules in the middle-column panel
- Select the "Dependencies" tab on the right-column panel

And then for the module where you have your Java application as well as for each of the module dependencies you need:
 - Click "+" -> "Jars or directories" on the far right of the right-column panel
 - Navigate to the output folder of the module (e.g.: my_module/build/classes/main/java) and click "OK"
 - On the new entry to the Dependencies list, on the far right, change the select box from "Compile" to "Runtime"

After this, you should be able to execute the Run configuration you just created to run the simple Java application.

One thing to note is that, for my particular [quite involved] Android Studio project set-up, I have to manually build the project with gradle, from outside Android Studio in order to get my simple Java Application classes to build, before I run the application - I think this is because the Run configuration of type "Application" is not triggering the corresponding Gradle build.

Finally, this was done on Android Studio 0.4.0.

I hope others find it useful. I also hope Google comes around to supporting this functionality soon.

Comment: `I have to manually build the project with gradle, from outside Android Studio` How do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

I installed IntelliJ IDEA community version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

I tried opening my project that I started in Android studio but it failed when at gradle build.  I instead opened both android studio and intellij at same time and placed one screen next to the other and simply drag and dropped my java files, xml layouts, drawables, and manifest into the project hiearchy of a new project started in IntelliJ.  It worked around the gradle build issues and now I can start a new project in IntelliJ and design either an android app or a basic Java app.   Thankfully this worked because I hated having so many IDEs on my pc.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to do it using following steps:

1. Open Android Studio and select 'Import Project'.
   [image: Android Studio import a project]
2. Browse to your project folder in the browse window and select it.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in Android Studio 0.8.14:**
I was able to get a standard project running with minimal steps in this way:

In an open Android Studio project, click File > New Module.

Click More Modules > Java Library > Next, then fill in whatever you prefer for the names.

A new module will appear as a folder on the same level as your "app" folder in the Project Structure.  Open it and open the new Java class file.

You can then add your code, and choose Build > Run 'YourClassName'.  Presto, your code is running with no Android device!

Comment: How is this answer different from that of `@idunnololz`? Does yours work with gradle without any additional steps?

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect if you do File>Open... and then select pom.xml file.  Be sure to change the dropdown at the top-left of the sidebar that says "Android" to "Project" to see all your files.  Also I think it helps if the folder your pom.xml file is in a folder called "app/".

Disclaimer: My java project was generated by Google App Engine.

Comment: do you have to move your dependencies to the pom or will it see the gradle stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Spent a day on finding the easiest way to do this. The purpose was to find the fastest way to achieve this goal. I couldn't make it as fast as running javac command from terminal or compiling from netbeans or sublime text 3. But still got a good speed with android studio.

This looks ruff and tuff way but since we don't initiate projects on daily bases that is why I am okay to do this.

I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA community version and created a simply java project. I added a main class and tested a run. Then simply closed IntelliJ IDEA and opened Android Studio and opened the same project there. Then I had to simply attach JDK where IDE helped me by showing a list of available JDKs and I selected 1.8 and then it compiled well. I can now open any main file and press Control+Shift+R to run that main file.

Then I copied all my Java files into src folder by Mac OS Finder. And I am able to compile anything I want to.

There is nothing related to Gradle or Android and compile speed is pretty good.

Thanks buddies

Answer (score 0):

To run a java file in Android ensure your class has the main method. In Android Studio 3.5 just right click inside the file and select "Run 'Filename.main()'" or click on "Run" on the menu and select "Run Filename" from the resulting drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

on Android Studio 4.0 and above, you will get an option readily on the IDE,a green run icon to run the related main() class.

[image]

Comment: How to see Logs if we run a java application like this?