# Package does not exist when refrencing a java module Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an android application that requires a Java library application (which I also wrote) to run.

I followed idunnololz guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects) to add the project as a java library which seemed to add ok. My java project is called Osmosis and contains 2 packages search and common.

I then tried to reference my project, with Android Studio very helpfully asking if I wish to reference osmosis.  This seemed to resolve the error, with import Search.* being added to the top of my android class. However, when I run my application I get the error: package does not exist. Until I click run it shows no errors.

Can anyone give any advice on how to fix this?

I have tried invalidating the caches, cleaning and rebuilding the project

My settings.gradle seems to include the reference:

```
include ':app', ':osmosis'
```

and here is my build.gradle

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matt.windowrunner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

The errors:

```
Error:(48, 14) error: package search does not exist
Error:(448, 7) error: cannot find symbol variable Search
Error:(460, 7) error: cannot find symbol variable Search
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone give any advice on how to fix this?

Your `dependencies` closure does not pull in the library. Add `compile project(:osmosis)` after your other two `compile` lines in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For anyone else who may look at this, the :osmosis needs to be in '' so (':osmosis'). This had now led to a Local path doesn't exist error but I'm guessing that is something else.

Comment: Does `compile project` have to be after `testCompile`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: I am not aware that the order matters for most things -- I was just trying to provide more specific instructions to help with the edits here. One place where the order *does* matter is in manifest merging. Having `:osmosis` after `play-services` would mean that `play-services` manifest entries would be considered more important than `:osmosis` ones.