# package com.example.module.activity does not exist

Tags: android, gradle

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sampleapp.com.sampleapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi = 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    androidSupport = '25.0.1'
    junit = '4.12'
    espresso = '2.2.2'
    mockito = '2.2.26'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupport"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit"
    compile project(path: ':samplemodule')
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito"
}
```

**build.gradle(module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi = 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

ext {
    androidSupportLibrary = '25.0.1'
    espresso = '2.2.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportLibrary"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(5, 45) error: package com.example.module.activity does not exist
```

Referred all the following posts:

[Android Studio library “error: package does not exist”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422860/android-studio-library-error-package-does-not-exist)

[Why do packages from library module does not exist upon compilation, even when Android Studio shows no errors in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796114/why-do-packages-from-library-module-does-not-exist-upon-compilation-even-when-a)

[Package does not exist when refrencing a java module Android Studio 1.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881138/package-does-not-exist-when-refrencing-a-java-module-android-studio-1-0-1)

[Package does not exist when using separate App as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050097/package-does-not-exist-when-using-separate-app-as-a-dependency)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: In your app gradle file you specified the package name as `sampleapp.com.sampleapplication`. Are you using the same package name in the activity that throws the error? Or are you using? I think it should also be `sampleapp.com.sampleapplication`

Comment: sampleapp.com.sampleapplication is the main application package the error is throw for module package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

when I set `miniFyEnabled false` my issues were fixed. It's too weird as this is specified for release build type and I am debugging the application.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Rohit, "minifyEnabled true" makes sense.
It seems ProGuard removes everything from the library AAR by default. Proguard-rules configuration file should be filled in properly in order to refer the classes from the main application module. Example:

```
-keep public class you.library.package.name.** {
    public protected *;
}
```