# Heroku tutorial via a Java project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, heroku, android-gradle-plugin

I am having trouble using Android Studio for a pure Java project, I wondered if someone could help please?

I am trying to follow the following steps in a Heroku Java/Gradle tutorial:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku#push-local-changes

I am trying to use Android Studio to compile and run the example code here:
https://github.com/heroku/gradle-getting-started

I am trying to use the steps here for a pure Java project in AS (although doesn't seem very relevant for AS 2.3.3):
[Android Studio: create Java project with no Android dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957283/android-studio-create-java-project-with-no-android-dependencies)

The project doesn't seem to get the dependencies right. The code doesn't compile because it doesn't recognise the ratpack folder as a dependency:
[image]

I wondered if anyone had any advise or suggestions? I am wary of changing the code or project structure as it is Heroku tutorial code so should still work when deployed to Heroku.

Cheers,
Riz

Comment: AS doesn't recognize the src/main/java directory as a source dir. The ratpack folder is fine, but the Main is try in import a ratpack dependency with the `ratpack.` namespace.

Comment: Add package above!

Answer (score -1):

If this Main.java file is your Main Activity(launcher activity) then in Android you don't have to use this String[] args main method but you have to extend it by AppCompatActivity

Comment: I'm trying to use Android Studio as the IDE for a Java project not an Android one.

Comment: Android studio can be used only for Android projects, for Java projects use IntelliJ IDEA Community edition or netbeans or BlueJ, eclipse for simple Java Projects, personally I like IntelliJ IDEA :-)

Comment: From what I understand one can use AS for Java projects as its just IDEA CE underneath, you just need to hack it appropriately by removing certain files and directories. I tried following the steps in the link above but to no avail.

Comment: That's true but not efficient and less productive