# ClassNotFoundException error for Kotlin (non-android) project on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I attempted to create a normal Kotlin project (non-android, just desktop/command line project) with Android Studio 2.3.3.

I followed the steps as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29267962/571227) but with different `build.gradle` content whose content I shared [here](https://gist.github.com/haxpor/0a5dbb0d793015a1ab2a9c5cc4db2dd1).

Actually that content of `build.gradle` I copied from `build.gradle` file after generating a new project with IntelliJ Community Edition (2017.2).

Then I create a configuration to be able to run it on desktop with proper set up like Main Class, Working directory, and Use classpath of module. You can see in the image below.

[image]

and following is the project file structure I have

[image]

Then I sync the project, it succeeds. But error kicks in when I try to **Run** the project. I got the following error.

```
    "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/haxpor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/haxpor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.4-2/272a21c30432c943d618008fbbd34762eb0d6c8a/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.4-2.jar:/Users/haxpor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.4-2/fec983b2608a8a91a1b87dba18d247d692cf6b51/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.4-2.jar:/Users/haxpor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.1.4-2/168cc3f45c307edda6c867dd0635a7d451257551/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.1.4-2.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain io.wasin.testjavaapp.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.wasin.testjavaapp.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I saw the classpath parameter as supplied in above `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` has no related directory to my project. I don't know how to add classpath directory via gradle despite I set up it in configurations already.

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**:

The following is my `Main.kt` code. It's just for testing purpose. So just printing something out.

```
package io.wasin.testjavaapp

object Main {
    @JvmStatic fun main(arg: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello world")
    }
}
```

Also I updated `build.gradle` for Kotlin version to match the version of Kotlin plugin on Android Studio. It's now `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'`. Although still doesn't solve the problem.

**Update 2**

I checked inside `build` directory at the same level of `src` directory. There are no `.class` or `intermediates` files generated/built over there, only `kotlin-build/caches/version.txt` and that's it. No other files. So the problem might be due to the source files are not compiled at all?

**Update 3**

I tried creating a new module to see if it's the root cause or not. Also created `assets` folder just to act as Working Directory, rearranged source folder again to be as following.

[image]

We now have 2 modules.

1. `testJavaApp` - root one
2. `desktop` - consists of `Main.kt` and used as desktop executable

`testJavaApp` has the following code for `build.gradle`

```
group 'io.wasin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

also `desktop` module has following code for `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
project.ext.mainClassName = "io.wasin.testjavaapp.Main"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../assets");

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
```

Unfortunately, it still **didn't** work and it's the same error that shown up.

**Update 4**

@aristotll provided info in a comment that he tested with Android Studio and faced the same problem, but **not** with IntelliJ. He said it might be Android Studio bug. So I guess, I would try a few more times then decide whether it's solid enough to report as a bug. Thanks for taking time to testing out.

Comment: Not sure if this is it or not, but you have the wrong directory marked as the Java Source.  Note the blue 'src' directory in your screenshot.  The java directory two levels down should be your java source.  This can be edited in the project settings or by right clicking the src directory and unmarking it as source, then repeating for the java directory.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you said, still the same. I tried marking the directory that hold `Main.kt` file as source root, then run again, still didn't fix. Also tried creating `src/main/java` directory then mark it as source root, still didn't fix. Both produce the same error.

Comment: Maybe it is not a problem of your config, but AndroidStudio problem. I reproduce your error in AndroidStudio, but when import the same project into Intellij idea the app runs normally.

Comment: @aristotll thanks for testing it out! Appreciate it. I might try to report a bug (not sure I should or not) if I cannot find a way.

Comment: I have the same problem.The problem is that, the kotlin source code are build into build/classes/kotlin directory. but when you click run, it will find the class in build/classes/java directory.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem and solved it.

Add `runtimeClasspath files("build/classes/kotlin/main")` in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    runtimeClasspath files("build/classes/kotlin/main")
}
```

because Android Studio doesn't find classes in `build/classes/kotlin/main`. Add `runtimeClasspath` and it works!