# How to import existing java project into android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android studio project want to use existing java project code

I tried this way:

1. Click File > New Module. Select Java Library and click Next.
2. Filled the required fields and clicked Finish.

A new empty Java project library was created in my Android project.

I need to use existing(java project) code to  my  android studio project, how can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html read this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It is not possible to access with out gradle file**,

you can use these steps if your Java project in eclipse

1.Right Click on project select export a new window appears

2.Select generate gradle build file then the select project  click finish

It will create your project with gradle file,then you can easily import

File -> New -> Import module.....

Comment: My problem fixed,Thank you for your response.

Comment: i cant see step 2 option "generate gradle build" in my eclipse

Comment: me neither, dont see any step 2 option

Comment: Question asked and answered by same person but with different account. Even said thank for himself. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2):

**`Select  Import Project Instead Module`**

### To import a project to Android Studio:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu select **File > New > Import Project. .**
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml
   file and click Ok.
4. Select the destination folder and click Next.

For demo you may visit [Getting Started with Android Studio](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-android-studio--mobile-22958) for step by step approach  .

Details

> https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: This is applicable for only android eclipse project.But what i asked above is, importing java project (java project is not having manifest file so it won't allow to import) in android studio.

Comment: @user1846931 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects

Comment: According to above link,creating empty project need to copy and past code,but i have a huge code showing importing and dependencies errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a java project if it is a **Gradle** build project. Otherwise android studio not allow to import other java projects.

File >> New >> Import Project  and select the **Gradle build java** project

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following link can be referred to:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

**Import Eclipse Projects to Android Studio**

Import as a Project:

> Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
>
> ```
> From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project.
>
> Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, click Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc)
>
> Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.
>
> Select the destination folder and click Next
>
> Select the import options and click Finish.
> ```

**Importing a Gradle-based IntelliJ project**

> If you are already using Gradle with your IntelliJ project, you can
>   open it in Android Studio using the following steps:
>
> ```
> Click File > New > Import Project.
> Select your IntelliJ project directory, and click OK. 
> Your project will open in Android Studio.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

On *Android Studio 2.3.3*

**File** -> **New** -> **Import Project**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to choose the 'open an existing project' option, find your project, and then find the 'app' folder.  Click on this to highlight it and then click 'Ok'.  This will then import your complete project

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search gives you everything:
https://www.google.co.za/search?q=import%20project%20to%20android%20studio

> **To import a project to Android Studio:**
>
> 1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
> 2. From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project. ...
> 3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml
>      file and click Ok.
> 4. Select the destination folder and click Next.

Google has made this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

I have had issues before with this so I normally just create a new project and just copy all the classes, drawables, etc from the old project into the new project.

Comment: Not an a android studio project,I need to import java project in android studio!

Comment: This is applicable for only android eclipse project.But what i asked above is, importing java project (java project is not having manifest file so it won't allow to import) in android studio.

Comment: i did mention that could just copy all the files into a new project.