# How to add an existing java project as a module to an existing Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, module

I have two github repositories - one an Android Studio project and another a intellij Idea Java project. Right now i build jar from my java project and use that jar in Android Studio project. 
Is there a way I can add my existing java project as a sub-module in my existing Android Studio project so that I do not have to go through the hassle of creating a new jar every time I modify the java project?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197775/how-to-import-existing-java-project-into-android-studio