# How to integrate a java project into an existing Android Studios project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

I'm building my first Android app and I found a java project on github that I would like to integrate with my app. Is it possible for me to manually add the java files to my android project directory at

**app** -> **java** -> **com.example.appname**

The **src** -> **main** directory of the java client has a nested file structure so I'm not sure if this would cause issues.

I already tried the solution from this post but I didn't see the option presented in step 2
[How to import existing java project into android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197775/how-to-import-existing-java-project-into-android-studio)

Comment: "I found a java project on github" -- you could add it as a gradle dependency in your project.

Comment: So if I do a remote binary dependency to the github repo I don't actually need to import anything into the project? Would this impact performance?

Answer (score 0):

Please use java code in MainActivity.java or other Activity. It Will work.same code you applied on java will also work on Activity .java

Comment: The github repo has a lot of java files so it wouldn't be practical to just copy and paste the code into an activity

Comment: It will possible by reading code line by line and then apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can add java project as module to your android project.
Check Method 2 in this [link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

Comment: When I get to step 3 it tells me "Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project" and I can't click the finish button. I downloaded and unzipped the folder to my local machine

Comment: can you give link of that project