# (Android Studio) Working on a project through USB for multiple Laptop/PC

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I first created a new project and moved it to my USB so I can work on it on different Laptop/PC but the .xml Designs are all showing differently.

Is there another folder that Android Studio saves to that I need to put in the USB folder?

Thanks for your help

-Edit-
Thank you guys for helping me out but it was just my mistake... looking at the wrong .xml file thinking it was the same one.. ha.. ha...

Comment: It is a project in Kotlin or Java?

Comment: nope, all files related to project are placed inside project folder. maybe you have (very) different Android Studio version?

Comment: @Gonçalo Garrido The project is in Java

Comment: @snachmsm they were both installed using the same downloaded file so I don't think it would have a different version

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197775/how-to-import-existing-java-project-into-android-studio, I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: `a new project and moved it to my USB ` Sorry i have no idea what you did and what that has to do with different laptops. USB is a serial bus as you know.

Answer (score 1):

all files related to project are placed inside project folder. but if you have copied WHOLE project, then you have moved also (hidden) `.idea` folder, which may contain some visual params of AS related to this project, thus in previews XMLs may be rendered differently. I bet when your app is building properly on both workstations then app will look exacly same on particular device

for preventing such situation I would advice:

1. repository! (with proper ignoring configuration, e.g. [`gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore) file)
2. after moving whole folder and opening it in AS first thing to do: File -> Invalidate caches / Restart and do whole clean up

second option will clean up your project and strip from AS-instance-related, workstation-related and build-related files. you can check out which files/folders are such type (doesn't belong to project code) in linked `gitignore`. also note that with second option you will have to do such clean up every time when you move from one workstation to another, thus: just use some reposity!