# Is it possible to have a JAVA only console in Android Studio just like in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, console

Well i really find it difficult to use the logcat whenever i need to work on pure java code in android studio. The log cat just bursts info that i don't need. Some of you may tell me to use the "Log Level" or "Filter", but that doesn't help. I need the answer to my question as specific as possible, thanks.

Comment: If it's pure Java, would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196451/260697

Comment: Well thanks but my question was different, I don't want to use AS for Java only projects, I want to develop for Android and while doing that, I need a separate eclipse like console for JAVA only commands such as System.out.println(""); etc .. I can get this output in the AS Logcat, but I want a separate console, the AS shows extra and useless info, like a thousand lines per second when the debug is on, on a device