# Kotlin : While running Hello Program getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, classnotfoundexception

```
package com.example.manish.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

fun main(arg : Array<String>){
    print("HI")
}
```

LogCat:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.manish.myapplication.MainActivityKt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:107)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823064/run-single-kotlin-class-with-main-function-in-android-studio

Comment: Problem is seems same but still exist

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a known issue in Android Studio and Kotlin inter-operation.

When you try to run a Kotlin class from a non-Android (e.g. pure Java + Kotlin) module, it does not add the separate directory, into which the Kotlin classes are compiled, to the classpath.

The workaround is to add these lines to your module's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeClasspath files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
}
```

This will work for the `main` source set. To do the same for tests, use `testRuntimeClasspath` and `compileTestKotlin` respectively.

Comment: After doing this I am getting 
Error:(36, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compileKotlin' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I am getting error: `Could not get unknown property 'destinationDir' for task ':compileKotlin' of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.`

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Android applicaton or a regular application? We can’t have a main function in an Android application; it has to be a regular desktop project.

But I dont why it is :)