# Running Kotlin scripts on desktop in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have Android Studio installed,  I know Android Studio has Kotlin support for *android applications*, however I am still learning the basics (Hello World, printing, basic things) and I would just like to run some basic programs.

Is there a way I can run simple (preferably single file) Kotlin scripts from Android Studio (maybe something [the online tester](https://try.kotlinlang.org/)) for testing, without going straight into the Android API and going straight on Android?

Installing the command line [version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) is not a desirable option for me as I don't have the Java SDK (I am hoping for a way around intalling it).  I also do not have Intellij Idea .

Comment: Why don't you use IntelliJ IDEA? It has similar (rather identical) workflow to Android Studio. Its community edition is free. It handles the SDK installation part. [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started.html)

Comment: @rushi Thank you,  I have seen that page (but didn't realise it dealt with the SDK for me),  while I understand it's the easiest option I don't really want to keep installing extra tools, to remove them later.  I was hoping I could just run in Android Studio until I moved on from complete basics and to developing Android properly but if I have no other option that is what I will have to do.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects) might be helpful. I guess running "pure" kotlin script would be same as for "pure" java. However, I have not done this myself.

Comment: @rushi  Thank you, that is exactly what I am hoping to acieve only in Kotlin, I might be able to get it working ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

First create a normal project. Then go to:

> File menu -> New -> New Module -> Java Library

After that set your build.gradle as:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Then create a new kotlin file with the main method

[image: kotlin code]

To execute just click on the play/run green button on the left of the main method as seen in the image above.

And you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I think Kotlin single file doesn't run as a module like java.
The easiest way is to create a new Java library module like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects/26196451#26196451), and configure it for Kotlin. After that make 2 classes, a Java class and a Kotlin class. Call your Kotlin methods from the Java main function. [Check my complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234812/9937309)..

Answer (score 0):

I can execute Kotlin class by simply doing right-click to the Kotlin class, and click on "Run '[classname]'  (Ctrl+Shift+F10) " and it works.

I don't see the reason why you should create a new module, or do workarounds...