# How to run single Kotlin class from Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, program-entry-point, android-studio-3.0

I am new to Kotlin development and I have created a separate Kotlin class in Android Studio as below :

```
  class MainClass{

    fun main(args: Array<String>)  {
        println("Hello World");
    }
 }
```

But, How can I run this kotlin class, and where the output will be generated.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823064/run-single-kotlin-class-with-main-function-in-android-studio

Comment: Android studio shows me a kotlin icon to left of main method and when I click on this icon, It shows me below three option:   ::::: (NOT IN MY CASE- not showing icon)

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714573/4936904

Comment: Where is this practice popular (putting main fun in Android code)?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky We can test and practice kotlin in android studio.

Answer (score 5):

your main function has to be a top-level function. 
Try this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)  {
        println("Hello World");
    }
```

In order to run it, just click on green the icon next to the function name in AS.

[Check out this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azg1J.png)

Comment: Top level means where in Activity ? inside onCreate() ?

Comment: okay got it. But, it giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.jaimin.kotinsetupdemo.MainClassKt
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

Comment: Create new kotlin file and then paste the above code, after that click the green play icon  on the left side of function name.. You will get the output in your Run tab on the bottom left of the screen.

Comment: +1 @JaiminModi Only way I can work around it is by adding this to gradle file: 
`sourceSets {
        main {
            main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }`
and oddly, the gradle file needs to be re-synced for every run!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, You will see a run icon near function.

```
class Test {
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            fun main(args: Array<String>) {
                println("Hello test!")
            }
        }
    }
```