# how to write runnable method like "fun main()" in kotlin with java in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

in the Kotlin if you out of the class write this code

```
fun main(){
System.out.println("ali")
}
```

you can run this method without run emulator. android studio show play icon first the method if you write this code in Kotlin and you can run only this method.
I want do it in Androidstudio Java. are you know how do it?
thank you

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a class? `public class Main { public static void main(String... args) { System.out.println("Hello"); } }`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823064/run-single-kotlin-class-with-main-function-in-android-studio

Comment: Tip: in Kotlin or Java, if you type `psvm` and hit Enter, it generates this function for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main in java is:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        //you code here
    }
}
```

If this solution doesn't work you can use the Junit test case in order to run one specific method