# Android Studio and Java (JEE) projects

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, android-studio-3.0

Is there any way to use Android Studio (not Intellij) and make it work fully with Java projects? I tried to open a Maven-based ejb project I have here but it seems that it doesn't recognize it.

I would like to use Android Studio, since my company forbids non-approved software, so I could use Android Studio (the company uses it for mobile projects) or Eclipse.

And going back to Eclipse is worse than firing.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use Android Studio for the plain Java projects. You can use IntelliJ IDEA Community (free and open source) or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

[Check this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for the differences. As you are working on Java EE, consider the Ultimate version.

> since my company forbids non-approved software

Ask your company to approve IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily develop & test java libraries and run standalone java applications (with static `main` method) that use gradle as their build system (maven functionality seems to be removed).

Web application support seems to also be removed (I haven't done web development using intellij though, so I may be wrong). You can still develop classes that are a part of your web app, but there's no any special support for web descriptors nor web content etc.

I haven't tried any EJB development. I guess it's similar like with web apps: you can develop java code, but no other support on top of this.