# Java and Gradle - Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to simply debug hello Java, but some gradual error is causing failure while debugging my code.

```
package learning.javalearning;   
    public class demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello J");
    }
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Initialization script `'C:\Users\JERRI._PC\AppData\Local\Temp\demo_main__.gradle' line: 20`
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project `':app'`.
  `Could not create task ':app:demo.main()'. SourceSet with name 'main' not found.`
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: You need to tweak android studio in case you want to run the normal Java program in the IDE.

Comment: thank you. Can you please explain how to do tweaking

Comment: @JDChristo can you public the file `build.gradle`?

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/q/16626810/7639056