# Android Studio "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception." error

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hello everyone I'm using A.Studio latest version but I need some help.
I already installed Android Studio and I wanted to check it. I created Main.java which is basic code.
And i wrote those codes for check it. I researched many times but i couldn't solve this problem i need help.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Testing Java");
    }
}
```

Then I debugged the codes A.S sent me error log. You can see the below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\canpi\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__1.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:Main.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 326ms
```

Thanks for help, regards.

Comment: Android apps do not use a `public static void main`. Please seek out some tutorials for basic Android apps.

Comment: No i just wanted to try i created no activity project and i have just created new>java class and Main.Java i try to learn java and i'm doing pratice on it, but doesn't work i think i didn't explain myself.

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose Android Studio, then, but even if you create a No Activity project, it's still an Android app project. I've never tried running a straight Java program in Android Studio, but you'll have to set it up a little differently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16626810.

Comment: @MikeM.  I am an extreme level newbie right now, anyway long and short of it I'm trying to follow a udemy lesson plan to learn. Getting to the very basic java stages. The project just involves making a single java class to run a hello world application... never imagined that would be what throws me out of a loop. it's on no-activity