# How to start a method in a mainactivty using receiver?

Tags: android, methods, broadcastreceiver

I'm using BOOT_UP_COMPLETE `BroadcastReceiver` in my program.
I need to start a method from my MainActivity (I found only to start an Activity or Service from a BroadcastReceiver).

In my code below, I need to start `InitMorning` method.

How to code it?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        //private Context mContext;
        public static int isMasterThreadRunning = 0;    
        Intent intent = null;
        private boolean isActivityExitInProgress = false;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.e("MainActivity : onCreate : Enter");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if(isMasterThreadRunning == 1)
            {
                SetButtonTitle("Stop Monitoring");
            }
            else
            {
              isMasterThreadRunning = 0;
            }
            Log.e("MainActivity : onCreate : Exit");  

        }



        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void startMonitoring(View view) {
            if(isActivityExitInProgress == false)
            {
              if(isMasterThreadRunning == 0) {
                InitMonitoring();
              }
              else if(isMasterThreadRunning == 1) {
                stopMonitoring();
                isActivityExitInProgress = false;
              }
            }
          } 

        public void SetButtonTitle(String buttonTitle)
        {
          Button start_monitoring_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start_monitoring);
          start_monitoring_button.setText(buttonTitle);
          if(buttonTitle == "Stop Monitoring")
          {
            start_monitoring_button.setEnabled(false);
          }
        }

        public void InitMonitoring()
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity : startMonitoring : Going to start master thread : Enter");
            MasterThreadService.mContext = getBaseContext();
            SetButtonTitle("Stop Monitoring");
            intent = new Intent(this, MasterThreadService.class);
            startService(intent);

            isMasterThreadRunning = 1;
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            Log.e("MainActivity : startMonitoring : Going to start master thread : Exit");
        }

        public void stopMonitoring()
        {
          Log.e("MainActivity : stopMonitoring : Enter");
          isActivityExitInProgress = true;
          SetButtonTitle("Start Monitoring");
          Log.e("MainActivity : startMonitoring : Calling exitFromApp");
          // Make a call to exit and clean everything : exitFromApp
          MasterThreadService.exitFromApp();
          if(intent == null)
          {
              Log.e("MainActivity : stopMonitoring : NULL POINTER ACCESS NEED TO INVESTIGATE");
          }
          else
          {
              stopService(intent);
          }
          isMasterThreadRunning = 0;
          Log.e("MainActivity : stopMonitoring : Exit");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Fllo thx for removing that caps lock issue.

Comment: @rekire It seemed yelling on us ^^

Comment: @ Fllo thanks for your help.but i didnt receive my solution yet :(

Comment: @saravana Hi, did you try my answer below? Did you succeed?

Comment: @Fllo..thank you very much..yes its works :)i dont have reputation dude..

Comment: @saravana good news! Happy coding.

Comment: @Fllo i need to launch a application in android without any user  interface..is it possible?when launcher icon pressed the the app should be started..do you have any suggestions? or if you have any source code example  provide me.

Comment: I don't understand clearly your question. But it seems you try to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2704084/2668136 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526074/android-activity-with-no-gui.. If you cant achieve it, post another question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can read on it, you need to attach your `Activity` in your `BroadcastReceiver`.

You must to **create your BroadcastReceiver dynamically**.  Then, use `setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity)` method in your Activity when you define and call the BroadcastReceiver and **attach your Activity inside the receiver class** with `setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity mainactivity)` method. Finally, call your Activity method with the following: `mainactivity.methodInActivity();`. This should do the trick.

You can find how do this on [Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934535/2668136) and you have another example on [Call activity method from broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929801/2668136).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a static reference. Change

```
public void InitMonitoring()
```

To

```
public static void InitMonitoring()
```

Then call the method from your service like:

```
MainActivity.InitMonitoring();
```

This is how I would do it. Don't know if it's the best way though.

Comment: if i change it to static then the errors say to modify all to static.it says not be able to reference non-static variables.